# APC cache installation with pear

Tags: php, macos, apc

I am trying to install APC cache on my mac osx(Maverick). But after running the command 'pear install apc', I am getting an error as below:

```
/private/tmp/pear/install/APC/apc.h:61:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
```

How to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have PHP development libraries installed as well, or PECL can't compile the library. In EL5/6 this means you need `php-devel` installed.

And could I suggest you use [Zend Opcache](http://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache) instead? If you're using 5.5 it comes installed (in El5/6 use `php-opcache`)

Comment: Thanks for the clue. However, seems like php-devel is depreciated somehow? Finally, I got it by installing from here:http://php-osx.liip.ch/ . Also, my application usage doctrine and seems like there is no support for php-opcache there, as didn't find any specific cache class for that, or is there any?

Comment: Ah, this is for a Mac. You can ignore the EL5/6 stuff. But you can't get around needing PHP development installed. If you don't have a pre-compiled version then you have to have the dependencies to do the compile yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try running "xcode-select --install" first, then pecl install apc again.